# IPv4 address with PHP

Tags: php, ipv4

I want to get the IPv4 address, but not the localhost address (127.0.0.1).
I just get ::1.

i tried it with `$ip = getenv ("REMOTE_ADDR");`

and

```
$ip = getenv ('SERVER_ADDR');
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the client IP address in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003145/how-to-get-the-client-ip-address-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

Comment: with this i just get ::1. Any other solutions?

Comment: if you are working on localhost 127.0.0.1 is your server ip.

Comment: I know but in a website of my friend my ip is my real ipv4 ip and i dont know how he did that. eg. In my website it is 127.0.0.1 and in his site it is 192.xxx

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got the answer at the same day. You can see it below:

```
    function getIP() {
    $ip = $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'];

    if (PHP_OS == 'WINNT'){
        $ip = getHostByName(getHostName());
    }

    if (PHP_OS == 'Linux'){
        $command="/sbin/ifconfig";
        exec($command, $output);
        // var_dump($output);
        $pattern = '/inet addr:?([^ ]+)/';

        $ip = array();
        foreach ($output as $key => $subject) {
            $result = preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $subpattern);
            if ($result == 1) {
                if ($subpattern[1][0] != "127.0.0.1")
                $ip = $subpattern[1][0];
            }
        //var_dump($subpattern);
        }
    }
    return $ip;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You get the IPv4 address with [`gethostbyname()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gethostbyname.php), for example with `gethostbyname($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])`.